# using Tensorflow Estimator exported model on Android app

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I have an Tensorflow model trained using the Estimator & Dataset APIs and I would like to use it locally on an Android app.

Can someone point me to a good reference and/or tutorial? I looked at the TensorflowInferenceInterface, but my understanding is it need you to specify which operator you want to feed the input to, but the Estimator/Dataset abstraction is at another level. So I am somewhat lost here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is official documentation for this question: https://www.tensorflow.org/mobile/prepare_models